# How to move multiple events in one day to another day?

Tags: macos, calendar, ios

How to move multiple events in one day to another day?

I know how to move multiple events to another calendar at once, but not to another day or week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cut/paste.

Shift select, Cmd/X, click new date, Cmd/V.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can hit control command left or right to move all selected items

And you can select all items in monthly view by CTRL + A. By scrolling up or down, you can specify the 6 weeks in a year that you want.